# Unit test with resources loaded with ClassLoader and Maven Surefire

Tags: java, maven, testing, classloader, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a JavaFX project that loads the FXML files using getClassLoader().getResource, for example:

```
Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("fxml/App.fxml").
```

The main code runs fine but when I run tests with Maven Surefire Plugin I have this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2459)
javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
```

Upon further investigation I discovered that when getClassLoader().getResource() is called while executing the test, the path it tries to resolve is in "target/test-classes" folder, whereas the resources reside in "target/classes" folder. How do I solve this problem? 
My project follows Maven's default structure if that is relevant.

Edit: added the line of code that does the resource loading

Answer (score 0):

When running tests in Maven, the classpath is comprised of both `target/classes` and `target/test-classes`

**target/classes** is used to store compiled classes and resources (under src/main/java, src/main/resources)
**target/test-classes** is used to store compiled test classes and test resources (under src/test/java and src/test/resources respectively)

You don't show the code that does`getClassLoader().getResource()` and the most important is the parameter of this getResource - how does it get resolved in runtime (during the test), so its hard to say more, but probably the issue is that this parameter is not specified correctly.

For example, if its file `src/main/resources/sample.xml` it should be resolved as:

```
getClassLoader().getResource("/sample.xml")
```

Comment: Nope. It should be sample.xml, not /sample.xml. /sample.xml is when you use SomeClass.getResource().

Comment: The code is Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("fxml/App.fxml"). The app itself works when I run it in the IDE as well as a fat JAR.